# java.lang.NullPointerException while deserializing with gson

Tags: json, gson, deserialization

Hello everyone i have some trouble to deserialize my json with gson, when i try to deserialize into my List i dont catch any errors but whenever i try to display the content of the List i got a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Here is the json:

```html
{
  "_id": "577f81286ed8b475f5faf6fb",
  "title": "bad (feat. vassy) [radio edit]",
  "album": "Listen",
  "artist": {
    "_id": "577f81140e8784358e32ae2d",
    "name": "david guetta"
  },
  "genre": {
    "_id": "577f81140e8784358e32ae2e",
    "name": "dance"
  },
  "duration": "2m50s",
  "year": 2014,
  "artwork": {
    "small": "https://i.scdn.co/image/f59354f8d3f2841e44c1bd7aa0cd55a22843cfc7",
    "medium": "https://i.scdn.co/image/9b092f765831793404d46b816d688135ff32735f",
    "large": "https://i.scdn.co/image/6e94ab39c917096d876b895dbab0019953d27a96",
    "default": "https://i.scdn.co/image/6e94ab39c917096d876b895dbab0019953d27a96"
  },
  "extraGenres": [],
  "extraArtists": []
}
```

Here is my model:

```html
public class SongDetails {

    public String _id;
    public String title;
    public String album;

    public String duration;
    public int year;

    @SerializedName("artist") Artist artist;
    public static class Artist {
        public String _id;
        public String name;
    }

    @SerializedName("genre") Genre genre;
    public static class Genre {
        public String _id;
        public String name;
    }


    @SerializedName("artwork") Artwork artwork;
    public static class Artwork {
        public String small;
        public String medium;
        public String large;
        @SerializedName("default")
        public String defaultX;
    }

    @SerializedName("votes") public VotesPlayer votes;
    public static class VotesPlayer {
        public int upVotes;
        public int downVotes;
        public int standing;
        public String by;
    }
}
```

I try to deserialize like this:

```html
Gson gson = new Gson();
Log.d("playdetails to des", toDeserialize);
// toDeserialize = {"_id":"577f81286ed8b475f5faf6fb","title":"bad (feat. vassy) [radio edit]","album":"Listen","artist":{"_id":"577f81140e8784358e32ae2d","name":"david guetta"},"genre":{"_id":"577f81140e8784358e32ae2e","name":"dance"},"duration":"2m50s","year":2014,"artwork":{"small":"https://i.scdn.co/image/f59354f8d3f2841e44c1bd7aa0cd55a22843cfc7","medium":"https://i.scdn.co/image/9b092f765831793404d46b816d688135ff32735f","large":"https://i.scdn.co/image/6e94ab39c917096d876b895dbab0019953d27a96","default":"https://i.scdn.co/image/6e94ab39c917096d876b895dbab0019953d27a96"},"extraGenres":[],"extraArtists":[]}
try {
       Response r = gson.fromJson(toDeserialize, Response.class);
       Log.d("deser details", r.myPlaylistDetails.size()+"");
    } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }

public class Response {
        public List<SongDetails> myPlaylistDetails;
    }
```

I got this error

W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

at the line of the : "Log.d("deser details", r.myPlaylistDetails.size()+"");"

Comment: This question is very broad. Try to narrow it down to the simplest possible problem case, for example, does it work when your model and sample data only have one field? Do you see any runtime errors? See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you, i found a fix for my problem, i will do that for my next post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced

```
Response r = gson.fromJson(toDeserialize, Response.class);
```

by to deserialize my json properly

```
SongDetails r = gson.fromJson(toDeserialize, SongDetails.class);
```

then display my details like this:

```
Log.d("deser details", r.title);
```